# including 404 page in post page

Tags: posts, 404-error

I created custom query var. So I need to include 404 page if query var not exists.

```
function add_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^custom_post_type/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?post_type=custom_post_type&name=$matches[1]&sub_pages=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_rewrites' );

function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){ 
$vars[] = "sub_pages"; 
return $vars; 
} 
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );
```

For example:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'sub_pages' ) == '' ) {
    //Normal Content
} elseif( get_query_var( 'sub_pages' ) == 'example' ){
    //Example Content
} else {
    //Include or Load 404 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do it would be to have a whitelist of pages, and to check the requested page against that list *before* the query is run.

```
function my_parse_query( $wp_query ) {
    if( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['sub_pages'] ) ){
        $sub_pages = array(
            'example',
            'another'
        );
        if( ! in_array( $wp_query->query_vars['sub_pages'], $sub_pages ) ){
            $wp_query->set_404();
            status_header( 404 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'my_parse_query' );
```

Then, once you reach the post type template, you know that if `sub_pages` is set at that point, it contains one of your defined valid pages.

Comment: My array is like that         $sub_pages = array(
            'example',
            'another'
        ); when I try to connet which sub_pages is afsfaasdf it redirects me to main post. But I want to show 404 page. There is no global $wp_query but you used with par.

Comment: `$wp_query` is just what I named the argument passed to the function, you could name it `$query` or `$kittens`, it's local to the function and is not related to the global `$wp_query`. It redirects because of the [`redirect_guess_404_permalink()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_guess_404_permalink) function that fires on any kind of 404 in WordPress. You could conditionally override that, but I'm not sure why you'd want to do that, I would prefer the 301 redirect personally.

Comment: I would prefer the 404. Because 404 is better for SEO when if that page is not exists. You need to 301 when you change your URL of page. But I am new with wordpress. I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: First of all, how are requests for these non-existent pages happening? How were those links generated? If the links are already out there and indexed, it's better for SEO to 301 those "versions" to the base page. Anyway, I think I've written some answers around how `redirect_guess_404_permalink` works, maybe you can find something in a search. I'll look at it tomorrow otherwise, I'm signing off for today.

Comment: There is no request for these non-existent pages.  I am still researching for 404.  Actually your cod is working. Because there is no non-existent page when I try to connect. But it redirect to main post. I see that when I try to connect example.com/boo it redirect me to example.com/books. Can it work like that?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. You're asking if it can work the way it already works? It redirects exactly the same way your books example does- it finds the closest match. There is no benefit to a 404 in this case.